# Where in android studio can I change the appbar text?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

[image]

I'd like to change and align the text, and possibly add features on appbar in the screen above.
However, it'd be best if I could find and modify the text and align it IF I don't intend to add features.
But then I wasn't able to find where in android studio I could change the text.

I thought I could find one in the main activity xml file but I couldn't. I looked up at themes.xml and AndroidManifest.xml but couldn't find a clue.
Here is first 13 lines of my main activity xml file just in case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="480dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

So, to cut it short, where in android studio can I change the text in toolbar? or appbar? above in the screen without having to create toolbar.xml? (+ align the text in the center and change text color)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparantly you don't have toolbar implemented in your xml layout

- In Your style file make sure you set it to noActionBar

```
   <style name="Theme.ChatApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

- Then you have to add your own toolbar

```
   
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_dashboard_24"
                app:title="here you can put your title"/>
```

- In your activity reference your toolbar in your onCreate

```
 setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
```

PS : If you are using MaterialToolbar please consider add this material library

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Comment: Does it mean that I have to add my own toolbar to change text?

Comment: Yes you ll have to go to your style file and set it to noActionBar , then you add your own in your layout , afterr that you reference it in your activity , you can either change it programatically or in your toolbar file in xml file

Comment: I added all the elements you mentioned, but I'm not sure why but the screen doesn't show action bar at all, do you have any clue what I could have missed?

Comment: since you re using constraintlayout , make sue you you have constrainted your views and also make sure you have called setContentView() where you pass you layout reference

Comment: It still didn't work but I'll work on it and get back to this post once I come up with a solution. Thank you for helping out!

Comment: I worked on it again and it worked fine. I don't know what I missed, but it is indeed working. Thank you!